# Apache poi table (XWPFTable) not generating properly

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

There is a lot of tutorials on apache poi, but I have problems with table creation. 
I'm trying this code:

```
public class CreateTable
{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        //Blank Document
        XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

        //Write the Document in file system
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("create_table.docx"));

        //create table
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
        //create first row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
        tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one, row one");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two, row one");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three, row one");
        //create second row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
        tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("col one, row two");
        tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("col two, row two");
        tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("col three, row two");
        //create third row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow();
        tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("col one, row three");
        tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("col two, row three");
        tableRowThree.getCell(2).setText("col three, row three");

        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("create_table.docx written successully");
    }
}
```

But in Libre office ubuntu table has infinity width, and when I load it to google doc, there is just nothing in this document. 
Setting width of table doesn't help.
What I'm doing wrong? 
Help please ((

Answer (score 0):

You can set width in following way:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(1,2);
table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(6000));
table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(2000));
table.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("1A");
table.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("1B");
XWPFTableRow newrow = table.createRow();
newrow.getCell(0).setText("2A");
newrow.getCell(1).setText("2B");
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code works just fine!

XWPF is for creating `.docx` documents. If you need to work with `.doc` you'll have to use HWPF.

Also... The XML structure of these documents is different. The formatting problems, you mentioned, might be caused by that.

Comment: The question is about .docx and XWPF. I can confirm that this problem exists. Haven't found solution yet...